# Issue with decomposing xts objects with R

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I am unable to figure out with I can't decompose the time series below. Any ideas why ?

```
data(co2,package = "datasets")
library(lubridate)
library(xts)
plot(co2)#ok
decompose(co2)# ok


my_co2 <- xts(co2,order.by = seq(from=dmy(01011959),to=dmy(01121997),length.out = 468))
plot(my_co2)
```

`my_co2` and `co2` seem to be identical..

```
decompose(my_co2) #
```

> Error in decompose(my_co2) : time series has no or less than 2 periods

I don't understand why this happens. Any ideas?

EDIT :

```
my_co2_v2 <- xts(frequency = 12,co2,order.by = seq(from=dmy(01011959),to=dmy(01121997),length.out = 468))
frequency(my_co2_v2) # still 1 !
attr(my_co2_v2, 'frequency')<- 12
frequency(my_co2_v2) # ok, it's 12
plot(decompose(my_co2_v2)) # still not good
```

you are right `plot(decompose(ts(my_co2_v2,frequency = 12)))` work, but it seems a little bit twisted. Is there a bug un xts regarding frequency ?

Comment: This happens because the `frequency` of **my_co2** is **1**. Maybe try `decompose(as.xts(co2))`

Comment: `decompose(ts(my_co2, frequency = 12))` does work. The frequency for the created xts shows as 1.  `frequency(my_co2)`
`frequency(co2)`